# Is there any data on the percentage of internet users who use in-browser translation vs. widgets provided by websites?

Tags: translation

I have long used Google Translate Widget, which was discontinued in 2019, but still works on existing sites. A similar product, Microsoft translation widget, was [also discontinued](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/blog/2019/06/27/the-translator-web-widget-will-be-retired-soon/), leaving few options for some embedded javascript to translate pages.

Another option is translation APIs such as [Weglot](https://www.weglot.com), [GTranslate](https://gtranslate.io), or [Google translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate), which are more involving to set up, and not free.

When I want a website translated, I always use the build-in translation feature of my browser. I'm looking on information about whether most users know of that feature and use it. I work in the field of medical care so it's important to get information to users in the language of their choice.

My conundrum is: if 95% of users use the translator integrated with their browser, then it might not be necessary to use a translation widget at all; whereas if that number is only 20%, then I'll bite the bullet and develop it.